# Mass cross reference in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a txt file (A.txt) with 20,000 domain names, one per line. I have another txt file (B.txt) that contains thousands of Whois records compiled together. I want to see which domains in A.txt are not referenced in B.txt. It's trivial to do this one-by-one, but how can I do it in mass? Thanks

Comment: Is using [spreadsheets/Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160243/join-two-spreadsheets-on-a-common-column-in-excel-or-openoffice) out of the question?

Answer (score 0):

You could edit file **A.txt** to have lines of the style `example.com A other stuff` and file **B.txt** to have lines of the form `example.com B other stuff`. Then sort the two files together. Next run a Notepad++ regular expression replace, searching for `^([^ ]+) A .*\r\n(\1 B )` and replacing with `\2`. The effect is that any **A.txt** line that matches a **B.txt** is removed, leaving the **B.txt** line. In case there are multiple **A.txt** lines that match one **B.txt** then run the replace two or more times until no lines are replaced. Finally, delete the **B.txt** lines (use a regular expression to find and mark lines looking for `^([^ ]+) B` then remove bookmarked lines) leaving the unmatched `A.txt` lines.

Not knowing the format of the source files A.txt and B.txt I cannot suggest a regular expression to put the URL followed by an A or B at the start of the lines.