# Excel: VLOOKUP matching one column to another sheet and joining the data

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm running into issues with VLOOKUP formula. I've been looking at tutorials and even followed another example explaining [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160243/join-two-spreadsheets-on-a-common-column-in-excel-or-openoffice) but the cells still say #N/A.

This is my formula.

=VLOOKUP($L2,surveydata,M$2,FALSE)

I'm trying to match the values in column L (phone) on one sheet with another sheet that contains phone as well (and labeled all the data as 'surveydata'), and then pull all the columns after into the original sheet.

```
== Table A ==        == surveydata ==     == Table result ==
Column L             Column A, B, C       Column L, M, N
Phone                Phone,Fname,Lname    Phone,Fname,Lname
012                  789,John,Smith       123
789                  012,Stan,Smith       456,Jane,Smith
456                                       789,John,Smith
123                  456,Jane,Smith       012,Stan,Smith
```

Am I missing something entirely?

Answer (score 0):

The third argument of the [`VLOOKUP` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) is the **position** of the column whose data you want to return. You've used a cell reference `$M2` which won't work (unless column M is hard-coded with the value 2).

So, assuming the 'surveydata' named range refers to your lookup table, then in column M you'll enter the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($L2, surveydata, 2, FALSE)
```

In column N you'll enter:

```
=VLOOKUP($L2, surveydata, 3, FALSE)
```

If `VLOOKUP` cannot find the value in the lookup table, it returns `#N/A`. You might want to use a combination of the `IF()` function and `ISNA()` functions to detect #N/A cases and display a more graceful error, message, or just an empty string.

Also, take a look at [this page from Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-correct-a-N-A-error-in-the-VLOOKUP-function-e037d763-ffc3-4fae-a909-89c482d389b2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) which explains how the `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` functions can be used as an alternative to `VLOOKUP()` - the difference is that you can specify the column you want returned, instead of the column's position.